# Feedthrough capacitor in analog switches

Tags: capacitor, switches, analog

I'm just wondering if anyone knows what feedthrough capacitor is, and how it can affect our switch.

As far as I'm concerned, if we use FETs as switches, feedthrough capacitors are the one that connect the input with the output. ( it can have values around 1pf-10pf).
If I'm right, what problems can cause these parasitic capacitances?

Thanks in advance.

p.s

When I say input tied to output, I'm refering about parasitic capacitances that connect the drain with the source.

Comment: Problem: you don't get an isolated input to output at high frequencies when the switch is supposedly open circuit. That's what capacitors do.

Comment: This means that at high frequencies the signal passes from input to output even though the device is turned off?

Comment: Yes of course. Nothing is perfect.

Comment: Compare it to two antennas close together. DC does no pass but high frequencies do. Sometimes you can short the input to the switch to reduce the effect. Depends on what is driving it.

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/354295/digital-potentiometer-capacitive-feedthrough for an example of what happens with feedthrough capacitance

Comment: This question is a little confusing to me. You should google "feedthrough capacitor" and see if that's what you mean. They are actual physical components. Do you mean feedthrough _capacitance_ or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FETs (MOSFETS) used in analog multiplexors have two series capacitors:

1) source-bulk (we assume there is no channel --DC path)

2) bulk-drain

These two capacitors in series set the high-frequency behavior **IF** the bulk is allowed to move freely.

Holding the BULK quiet is partly **your** responsibility, based on how firmly, how strongly, you control the GND and the VDD pins on the **silicon**.

Note I said **silicon**.

Different packages will have difference inductance, and even different pinouts and even different routing patterns (in the case of BGA, etc).

View your high frequency analog mux model as

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRD8Jq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>